# PHP: version_compare() returns -1 when comparing 5.2 and 5.2.0?

Tags: php

```
version_compare('5.2', '5.2.0'); // returns -1, as if the second parameter is greater!
```

Isn't 5.2 and 5.2.0 suppose to be equal? (isn't 5.2 and 5.2.0.0 are also equal)?

Comment: I did read the manual before asking the question, but just now I've learnt the meaning of "PHP-standardized version"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation says it compares 'two "PHP-standardized" version number strings'.

You're comparing one PHP-standardized version number string with one non-PHP-standardized version number string.

Comment: I asked this question because I'm using version_compare to compare also mysql version, zend version, and other plugins.. but I guess the word "PHP-standardized" means version_compare should be used only for comparing PHP version, right?

Comment: I'd say that's a pretty safe bet.

Comment: No, it will work with version numbers for other programs/libraries, but only if they follow the pattern described in the manual

Comment: @ceejayoz btw, why did I got a -1 for my question? I never knew version_compare() should be used only for php-versions, otherwise they could have named the function php_version_compare() :(

Comment: Did you see a pattern described in the manual @MarkBaker for "PHP-standardized" version number?  I could only find [a few examples and those air-quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php).

Answer (score 13):

Here's a tweaked compare function which behaves as expected by trimming zero version suffix components, i.e. `5.2.0` -> `5.2`.

```
var_dump(my_version_compare('5.1', '5.1.0'));           //  0 - equal
var_dump(my_version_compare('5.1', '5.1.0.0'));         //  0 - equal
var_dump(my_version_compare('5.1.0', '5.1.0.0-alpha')); //  1 - 5.1.0.0-alpha is lower
var_dump(my_version_compare('5.1.0-beta', '5.1.0.0'));  // -1 - 5.1.0-beta is lower

function my_version_compare($ver1, $ver2, $operator = null)
{
    $p = '#(\.0+)+($|-)#';
    $ver1 = preg_replace($p, '', $ver1);
    $ver2 = preg_replace($p, '', $ver2);
    return isset($operator) ? 
        version_compare($ver1, $ver2, $operator) : 
        version_compare($ver1, $ver2);
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Wrote a lot of unit tests for this and it works like charm :) Thank you

Answer (score 4):

5.2 and 5.2.0 are both PHP-standardized version number strings. AFAIU 5.2 represents 5.2.0, 5.2.1, etc. 
And result is logical, 5.2 could not be equal to 5.2.1 or 5.2.0 and either it could not be greater than 5.2.0 for example.
So only expected behavior is 5.2 < 5.2.0, 5.2 < 5.2.1, ...

Btw even the documentation states:

> This way not only versions with different levels like '4.1' and '4.1.2' can be compared but also ...

Comment: Exactly, the quality of PHP's documentation can really be a piece of joke. We need better standards.

Answer (score 1):

Quick PHP function to figure out whether a version is greater than other:

```
$v1 = "1.101.9999";
$v2 = "1.2";

if ( semver($v1, $v2) ) {
    echo "v1 is greater than v2";
}

function semver($v1, $v2, $version_separator = ".") {

    // DTSC
    $v1_sub = explode($version_separator, $v1);
    $v2_sub = explode($version_separator, $v2);

    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($v1_sub); $i++) {

        if ( !isset($v2_sub[$i]) ) {
            $v2_sub[$i] = 0;
        }
    
        if ( intval($v1_sub[$i]) > intval($v2_sub[$i]) ) {
            return true;
        } else if ( intval($v1_sub[$i]) < intval($v2_sub[$i]) ) {
            return false;
        }
    
    }

    return false; // Versions are equal - Change this value if you need a specific return for equal versions
}
```